# Conditions for convergences of a net

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, nets

I got stuck on this problem and got no clue to solve it. Can anyone one here help me? I really appreciate.

> > Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{A}$ the collection of all finite subsets of $X$, directed by inclusion. Let $f: X \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be an arbitrary function and for $A \in \mathcal{A}$, let $z_{A} = \sum_{x\in A}f(x)$. Then the set $< z_{A} >$ converges in $\Bbb{R}$ iff $\{x: f(x) \neq 0 \}$ is a countable set $\{x_{n}\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ and $\sum_1^\infty|f(x_{n})| \lt \infty$, in which case $z_{A} \rightarrow \sum_1^\infty f(x_{n})$

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\Leftarrow$ direction is pretty straightforward, I think.

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction, try the contrapositive.  There are two cases to consider; the case that the function has uncountable support, and the case where the function has countable support, but does not converge absolutely on that support. You have to show that $\langle z_A\rangle$ does not converge in either case.

The second condition is again pretty straightforward: if the series does not converge absolutely, then there is a sequence $x_{n}$ for which the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^{k}f(x_{n})$ does not converge, and you're done.

The more interesting case is when the function has uncountable support.  Use the pigeonhole principle to conclude that there is some rational $q$ such that the set $$\big\{x\in X \,\big\vert\, \vert f(x)\vert >q\big\}$$ is infinite.  It should be easy from there.

Comment: "if the series does not converge absolutely, then there is a sequence $x_n$ for which the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^{k}f(x_n)$ does not converge". Can you please explain about this point? I don't get it. Thanks

Comment: Suppose that there are only countably many $x\in X$ for which $f(x)\neq 0$. Fix an enumeration $\langle x_{k}\vert k\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$. Then we are saying that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\vert f(x_{k})\vert$$ does not converge. Let $\langle l_{j}\vert j\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ be such that the subsequence $\langle x_{l_{j}}\vert j\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ picks out those $x$ such that $f(x)>0$, and let $m_{j}$ be similar for the $f(x)<0$. If it were the case that both $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f(x_{l_{j}})$$ and $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f(x_{m_{j}})$$ converge, then $\sum f(x_{k})$ would converge absolutely.